# ImageView: Overlaying multiple images with alpha

Tags: android, imageview, layer

I'd like to be able to load multiple images into an `ImageView` and turn them on\off as needed.  Seems simple, but giving me plenty of trouble as I'm finding the image doesn't update after a change, even if I use `invalidate()`.

Inside a custom `ImageView`:

```
private Drawable[] drawables = new Drawable[6];
private Context _context;
private LayerDrawable layers;

private void ourClassDef(Context context)
{
    _context=context;

    Resources r = _context.getResources();

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    drawables[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.gun_blank);
    drawables[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.gun_base_green);
    drawables[2] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.gun_base_red);
    drawables[3] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.gun_coil_green);
    drawables[4] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.gun_coil_red);
    drawables[5] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.gun_trigger);

    layers = new LayerDrawable(drawables);        
    setImageDrawable(layers);       
}

public GunIconControl(Context context) {
    super(context);
    ourClassDef(context);
}
```

...

Then, turn each layer on\off with

```
layers.getDrawable(5).setAlpha(on?1:0);
```

-or-

```
layers.getDrawable(5).setVisible(on,true);
```

Is there a better way to control the layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [layerDrawable.setLayerInset](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#setLayerInset%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

**Edit:** Attaching OP solution

```
 if(on) {
      layers.getDrawable(5).setBounds(normal_bounds); 
 }
 else{
      layers.getDrawable(5).setBounds(out_of_bounds);
 }
```

Comment: Nice solution.  I ended up with:  
  if(on)
   layers.getDrawable(5).setBounds(normal_bounds);
  else
   layers.getDrawable(5).setBounds(out_of_bounds);
This works well.  Thanks!